# Getting ui:param value in Managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have the following `p:tabView`:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="false" activeIndex="#{navigationController.activeTabIndex}"
    onTabChange="tabChangeCommand([{name:'index', value:index}])">
    <p:tab title="#{adbBundle['nav.manageUser']}" id="manageUserTab">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <h:form id="manageUserListForm">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/userList.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="showOnlyActiveUsers" value="#{true}" />
                </ui:include>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{adbBundle['nav.manageRole']}" id="manageRoleTab">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <h:form id="manageRoleListForm">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/userList.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="manageRole" value="manageRole" />
                    <ui:param name="showOnlyActiveUsers" value="#{false}" />
                </ui:include>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

The two tabs both of them have same include, i.e., `userList.xhtml`. Inside this `userList.xhtml` I have placed a `h:outputText` to see the value of `ui:param` `showOnlyActiveUsers` for testing purpose:

```
<h:outputText id="showOnlyActiveUsers" value="#{showOnlyActiveUsers}" />
```

The value of this `h:outputText` changes from `true` to `false` on tab change and vice versa.

The managed bean `UserListController` which is in view scope is the back bone for `userList.xhtml`. Since it is in view scope it is instantiating once for all these two tabs.

I have a class `UserDataModel` which extends `LazyDataModel` of Primefaces. An instance of this class is present in `UserListController`. I am trying to set a value to a field of `UserDataModel` from the getter method of a `h:inputHidden`:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{userListController.showActiveOnly}" />
```

which is in `userList.xhtml` from `UserListController` as:

```
public String getShowActiveOnly() {
    ValueExpression expression = getFacesContext().getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(getFaceletContext(), "#{showOnlyActiveUsers}", Boolean.class);
    userDataModel.setShowOnlyActiveUsers(expression.getValue(getFaceletContext());
    return "";
}
```

BUT the value which is generated by `expression.getValue(getFaceletContext()` is always `false`. I was wondering why the value in the `h:outputText` changes from `true` to `false`, but the value generated by `ValueExpression` is always `false`?

How can I solve this issue. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

### Edit

```
protected final FaceletContext getFaceletContext() {
    return (FaceletContext) getFacesContext().getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
}
```

What I want to achieve is to pass the `ui:param` value to the managed bean and from there to the data model.

### Edit

`userList.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <h:form id="userListForm">
        <p:panel id="userListPanel" header="#{adbBundle['userList.panel.header']}" toggleable="true">
            <p:dataTable var="user" id="userTable" value="#{userListController.userDataModel}" lazy="true" paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorPosition="bottom"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100" widgetVar="userDataTable" styleClass="userTable" selectionMode="single">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="resetFiter" styleClass="dataTableResetFilter">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{adbBundle['filter.resetText']}" />
                            <p:spacer width="10" />
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-close" actionListener="#{userListController.resetUserTable}"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </f:facet>

                <p:column id="nameColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['name']}" sortBy="#{user.fullName}" filterBy="#{user.fullName}" styleClass="name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.fullName}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="statusColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['status']}" sortBy="#{user.active}" styleClass="center status" filterBy="#{user.statusText}"
                    filterMatchMode="exact" filterOptions="#{userListController.statusOptions}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.statusText}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="manageRoleColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['role']}" sortBy="#{user.role}" styleClass="center manageRole" filterBy="#{user.role}"
                    filterOptions="#{userListController.roleOptions}" rendered="#{manageRole != null and manageRole != ''}">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="roleRadio" value="#{user.role}" styleClass="roleRadio">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="user" itemLabel="User" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="manager" itemLabel="Manager" />

                            <p:ajax listener="#{userListController.changeRole}" />
                            <f:attribute name="user" value="#{user}" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

What I want is to get the current value of that `ui:param` from the `userList.xhtml` and pass it to the managed bean by some event and set it to the `datamodel`. It is also true that the `datamodel` is instantiating only once when the managed bean is created as it is in view scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this to display active users ,

```
<h:form id="userListForm">
    <p:panel id="userListPanel" header="#{adbBundle['userList.panel.header']}" toggleable="true">
        <p:dataTable var="user" id="userTable" value="#{userListController.userDataModel}" lazy="true" paginator="true" rows="10"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100" widgetVar="userDataTable" styleClass="userTable" selectionMode="single">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="resetFiter" styleClass="dataTableResetFilter">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{adbBundle['filter.resetText']}" />
                        <p:spacer width="10" />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-close" actionListener="#{userListController.resetUserTable}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{showOnlyActiveUsers and user.active}">
            <p:column id="nameColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['name']}" sortBy="#{user.fullName}" filterBy="#{user.fullName}" styleClass="name">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.fullName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="statusColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['status']}" sortBy="#{user.active}" styleClass="center status" filterBy="#{user.statusText}"
                filterMatchMode="exact" filterOptions="#{userListController.statusOptions}">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.statusText}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="manageRoleColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['role']}" sortBy="#{user.role}" styleClass="center manageRole" filterBy="#{user.role}"
                filterOptions="#{userListController.roleOptions}" rendered="#{manageRole != null and manageRole != ''}">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="roleRadio" value="#{user.role}" styleClass="roleRadio">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="user" itemLabel="User" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="manager" itemLabel="Manager" />

                        <p:ajax listener="#{userListController.changeRole}" />
                        <f:attribute name="user" value="#{user}" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
             </ui:fragment>   
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

also you can use boolean expression in this format

```
<ui:param name="showOnlyActiveUsers" value="false" />
```

Other solution could be to pass list of users to your ui include .Keep two methods 'userListController.userList' and 'userListController.activeUserList' and pass this as ui:param to your usersList.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. But my problem is not with some conditional rendering. The `userList.xhtml` has a `p:dataTable`, whose value is `UserDataModel`. `UserDataModel` extends `LazyDataModel`. Now from the `load` mthod of this model class I am fetching list of users. I need to show only active users in the first tab and all users including active and in-active in the second tab. The managed bean is in view scope so one instance of it (and also the model) is available for both the tab. My aim is to set `showOnlyActiveUsers` value to that model, by some event or by any other means.

Comment: Why are you tring to change your managed bean , keep your managed bean same with list of users and keep the logic in usersList.xhtml  to show or hide active users in different tab , you can achieve it by using  'showOnlyActiveUsers and user.active' where showOnlyActiveUsers will be passed true for one tab and false for other.

Comment: Other solution could be to pass list of users to your ui include .Keep two methods 'userListController.userList' and 'userListController.activeUserList' and pass this as ui:param to your usersList.xhtml

Comment: Thank you very much. Your last comment saved me. Why I didn't thought like this! Could you please add another answer same as the last comment so that I can accept that.